# How to sort search-results in Nautilus?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, files, sort

After upgrading to 18.04, I find that the File Manager will not allow sorting (date, type, name etc) after a search.  It does allow sorts prior to a search.

This change is not an improvement.

Comment: If you're missing features in Nautilus I recommend using Nemo. Nemo was forked from Nautilus some time ago. It still feels very similar but was not reduced in features like Nautilus was.

Comment: I added an new issue on github https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/888 but it seems that there is no intenstion so solve that behaivier. Upvote the issue anyway!

Answer (score 6):

### 1. Krusader

While **Nautilus** is the default file manager, there exist other like [**Krusader file manager**](https://krusader.org/index.html).

- It can be installed with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install krusader
  ```
- Open with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and enter `krusader` and than <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It provides a powerful search gui, eg sorting the search-results.
- If you want to set Krusader as the default file manager, run this command in Terminal:

  ```
  xdg-mime default krusader.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
  ```

  To test that change type

  ```
  xdg-open $HOME
  ```
- To revert this enter

  ```
  xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
  ```

[image]

---

### 2. [Nemo](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/nemo)

- It can be installed with

  ```
  sudo apt-get install nemo
  ```
- Open with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and enter `nemo` and than <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It provides a powerful search gui, eg sorting the search-results.
- If you want to set Nemo as the default file manager, run this command in Terminal:

  ```
  xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
  ```

  To test that change type

  ```
  xdg-open $HOME
  ```
- To revert this enter

  ```
  xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
  ```

[image]

Comment: Why `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`? The desktop shell seems to interop fine

Answer (score 5):

Allowing sorting was removed from Nautilus, and instead replace by sorting for "relevance" without a clear idea of what that means. See: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/209 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/374 and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778484

As with other suggestions, the only way to have this functionality is to replace nautilus with another file manager. Caja is a good option (default in Mate desktop, fork of Nautilus from Gnome 2), and also has caja extensions (apt-cache search caja-).

Comment: Thanks for the links. This problem is infuriating, and Gnome developers asking for use cases of sorting search results is bordering on insanity.

Answer (score 4):

You need to click on the drop down icon on the right of the text searched.

[image: screenshot]

For sorting from the columns that appears not to be the default settings anymore. As of now the bug is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1787282).

You can try other file managers like Thunar or PCMan File Manager which may offer same functionality.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this still doesn't let you sort the results. It just gives you options like searching for certain dates or file types.